# WAMP - mod_rewrite fails with incomplete local path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp, local

I'm trying to set up my PHP project on Windows & WAMP, but I ran into a very strange roadbump.

In my .htaccess I have the following catch-all redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L]
```

On Linux & Apache this works fine, for example: /some_alias/items redirects succesfully to my index.php file which handles the page request from that on.

However, with Windows, I get the following when accessing http://xx.xx.xx.xx/some_alias/index

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Users/username/workspace/project/some_alias/index.php was not found on this server.
```

My alias file is as follows:

```
Alias /some_alias/ "c:/users/username/workspace/project/some_alias/" 
<Directory "c:/users/username/workspace/project/some_alias/">

AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Is there a `/Users/username/workspace/project/some_alias/index.php` or where is the file you are trying to access?

Comment: The index.php file is at C:\Users\username\workspace\project\some_alias\index.php.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. Make sure the Options settings are correct for `mod_rewrite` adding this line in the .htaccess file at root: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`.

Comment: @faa: Thanks for your reply. Changing the Options did not help. I managed to get everything up and running by ditching the alias (linking to my Eclipse workspace) and instead just placing all my www files to the original WAMP htdocs dir (C:/wamp/www). I'm keeping this question open in case someone has the correct solution.